# Use this. in a function inside a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to get a *String* from my `data` in Vue 2, but I don't know how to get it from a function inside a function. Does anyone know how to? I'm using a library, *iziToast* library. **See the comments**, that's the part where I'm stucked.

```
data: () => ({
    myString: "Example string",
  }),

methods: {
showAlert() {
     iziToast.show({
        title: user.name,
        message: "¿Permitir que entre?",
        position: "bottomCenter", 
        buttons: [
          ["<button>Yes</button>", function(instance, toast) {
            // Function if Yes button is pressed
            alert(this.myString); // This won't work
            }, true], 
          [
            "<button>No</button>",
            function(instance, toast) {
              instance.hide(
                {
                  transitionOut: "fadeOutUp",
                  onClosing: function(instance, toast, closedBy) {
                    console.info("closedBy: " + closedBy); 
                  }
                },
                toast,
                "buttonName"
              );
            }
          ]
        ]
      });
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function signature as below & you'll have access to `this.myString`

`function(instance, toast) {` to `(instance, toast) => {`